# Problem Deploying SpringBootAplication of Heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I'm coding a api with spring-boot, using meaven, in my machine it runs. But when I tried to deploy it on heroku it gave me this error:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_6482326e_/src/main/java/com/XYZ/model/entity/Aclass.java:[4,15] package jdk.jfr does not exist
       [INFO] 1 error
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  14.045 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-07T20:03:49Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project XYZ: Compilation failure
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_6482326e_/src/main/java/com/XYZ/model/entity/Aclass.java:[4,15] package jdk.jfr does not exist
       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

I am using Java 14 locally.

I tried searching it on google, but nothing. Well, I hope someone knows what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All given answers are just workarounds, the real answer to this question is that Heroku runs per default `OpenJDK 8`

if you wish Heroku to use a different java version you add a file named `system.properties` in the root of the project, and in this file you define the `java.runtime.version` property to the selected java version.

For example:

```
java.runtime.version=14
```

you can read all about it here:

[Supported java versions Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions)